# Can I set CharSet for every page load? (Classic ASP)

Tags: unicode, asp-classic, vbscript, utf-8

I have made some changes to a Classic ASP application which breaks foreign letters unless "Response.Charset = "utf-8"" is set in every page... And it's a lot of pages...

Could I force the Charset to utf-8 for every page without having to set it in each page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure that `asp` files are served with this header.

In IIS 5.1/6, go to the website properties, click "File Types" and make sure the Content Type for `asp` files is `text/html;charset=UTF-8`.

IIS 7 has a [similar setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755170%28v=WS.10%29.aspx). Go to the level you need, in Features View, double-click MIME Types, find `asp`, select `Edit` and update to the correct value.

Comment: @Christian W - Same as IIS 6... Stuck on an XP box?

Comment: @Christian W - Perhaps this link will help. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx